# How do i list the full path of certain file type in a directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am currently struggling with generating a text file, which contains the full path of only the .sph files in the directory, or its subdirectories.

example:

tree

```
├── mwhw
│   ├── an151-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── an152-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── an153-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── an154-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── an155-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── cen1-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── cen2-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── cen3-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── cen4-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── cen5-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── cen6-mwhw-b.sph
│   ├── cen7-mwhw-b.sph
│   └── cen8-mwhw-b.sph
├── spk2utt
├── text
├── utt2spk
├── wav.scp
└── words.txt
```

How do i generate a text file which only provide me with the path of the .sph files here?

Comment: os.system is reaeaeaelly outdated, deprecated. Still open for a pythonic way?

Comment: Well.. I did found a solution a different way... So i don't need a different version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path relative to the current directory (`.`), you can use

```
find . -name '*.sph' > filelist
```

If you want the full *absolute* path, try

```
find $PWD -name '*.sph' > filelist
```

Comment: Could this be done without the use of PWD, I am sorry for not having explicitly stated it. This has to be runned in python script  in a os.system  call, $PWD is not possible..

Comment: @BobBurt I'm not a fan of using system calls for things like this - have you considered doing something like this [Find all files in directory with extension .txt in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)